# Efficiently "cancelling out" operations in a list

Tags: python, algorithm, list

I have a list of new actions that have been requested to be performed. There are only two types, subscribe and unsubscribe, or + and - actions. Each action has an `id` attached to it. For certain reasons, there may be two actions that effectively cancel each other out in this list - a + and a - action, *both* with the same id, cancel out - and since each action is somewhat expensive, I don't want to perform more than are necessary. So I want to search the list and cancel opposites. This sounds like a simple enough problem, and it is, but there might be a good amount of (300-ish) actions in a given list. Not a huge problem, but I was trying to find an algorithm that hits the sweet spot between efficiency and cleanliness, and I don't know the specific terms for this kind of problem so I can't find anything substantial by searching around.

Of course, some basic code would work perfectly fine. Eg in Python (though this question is not really specifically about Python):

```py
def perform_actions(actions_list):
    new_subscriptions = []
    new_unsubscriptions = []

    for action in actions_list:
        id_ = action.id_

        if isSubscribeType(action): # stand-in for some real check
            if id_ in new_unsubscriptions:
                new_unsubscriptions.remove(id_)
                continue

            new_unsubscriptions.append(id_)
        else:
            if id_ in new_subscriptions:
                new_subscriptions.remove(id_)
                continue

            new_unsubscriptions.append(id_)

    for action in new_subscriptions:
        # do subscription

    for action in new_unsubscriptions:
        # do unsubscription
```

This works but there's considerable duplication in the logic and it feels like too much machinery for such a simple thing. Not to mention it's pretty inefficient.

So, essentially, how can I make this function more clear and efficient without executing too many expensive actions at the end?

Comment: `action is "subscribe"` is never going to be `True` in your scenario, because `action` is not a string (it can't be, if it has an `id_` attribute) and strings are not guaranteed to be singleton objects. Don't use `is` unless you are testing for *identity* (such as when testing for `None`, a singleton, or enum values, also singletons).

Comment: So, as long as the `id_` attributes have the same value, subscribe and unsubscribe actions cancel out, and + and - actions cancel out? When you say "in succession", do you mean only if they are adjacent in the list?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, sorry I was only really using it as a stand-in for the actual check - it's not meant to be literal working code

Comment: @gmds, in succession in my case means anywhere in the list, not just adjacent. So if there's a + with id 1, and a - with id 1 anywhere, they cancel. Same for subscription actions in the same way.

Comment: Does order for subscribing and unsubscribing matter? E.g. should action A be subscribed before Action B, if neither has been cancelled out?

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, in my case order does not matter - so long as there are no actions that cancel out, they're independent of each other.

Comment: Does order matter? If you have "+1 +2 -1 +1", should the resulting sequence be "+1 +2" or "+2 +1"?

Comment: @tobias_k either one will work for me at least

Comment: And what about "double" subscriptions (or unsubscriptions)? If you have "+1 +1 -1", would the result be "(none)" or "+1"? Or could this never be the case?

Comment: @tobias_k this is effectively impossible in my case, but for the purposes of the question the answer should be (none)

Comment: @naiveai: my solution would result in a `+1`, because there is one more subscription than unsubscription. There will never be more than one subscription or unsubscription, however.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) (also known as mappings or dictionaries), to track subscriptions and unsubscriptions, where the key is the action id. Hash tables give you O(1) constant time lookups, so testing to see if an action id has been processed before is cheap. In Python, the `dict` type is such a hash table. With a hash table you can process your actions in O(N) time for N actions, so in *linear* time.

Your use of a Python list on the other hand, is not efficient because lists (arrays, sequences) require a *full scan* to test for membership. This means they take O(N) time to test if an action id has already been seen before, and your algorithm slows down as you add more actions, and your code takes O(N^2) (N times N) steps to process all N actions. As your actions list grows in size, processing the list takes *quadratic* time.

The added advantage of a hash table is that actions that are only listed for subscripting or unsubscribing (and not both) are de-duplicated. Action A being listed to be subscribed twice will end up being subscribed just once.

So, to implement this in Python, use the `dict` type. To make it easier to test if an action id has already been processed for the *opposite* change, you an create a tuple with two *dictionaries*. These map subscriptions and unsubscriptions per id. The tuple is addressed by index for 'unsubscribe' (`0`) and 'subscribe' (`1`), and you can trivially adjust this index to look in the 'opposite' bucket by subtracting from 1. So if Action A is being subscribed (index 1) then you check in `1 - 1` > item `0` in the tuple, and vice versa.

I'm assuming here that `action.change` is a string value set to either `'subscribe'` or `'unsubscribe'`, and that string can be used to map to indexes with an extra dictionary:

```
changes = ({}, {})  # unsub, sub
changemap = {'unsubscribe': 0, 'subscribe': 1}
for action in action_list:
    change = changemap[action.change]  # unsubscribe / subscribe -> 0 or 1
    if action.id_ in changes[1 - change]:  # 0 becomes 1, 1 becomes 0
        # action is listed twice for both subscribe and unsubscribe
        # cancel opposite and skip this action
        del changes[1 - change][action.id_]
        continue

    changes[change][action.id_] = action
```

Now you have two dictionaries with unsubscribes and subscribes, which can be processed separately:

```
for action in changes[0].values():
    # unsubscribe action

for action in changes[1].values():
    # subscribe action
```

If you are using Python 3.6 or newer, dictionaries produce their keys and values in insertion order, so the above will process all unsubscribes in the same relative order they were listed in the `actions_list`, and the same applies to subscribes.

If you *only* need the `action.id_` attribute to subscribe or unsubscribe an action, then you can replace the dictionaries with sets and only store the action ids. Sets do not remember insertion order, however.

If actions should be dropped *altogether* if they are listed at least twice with conflicting changes (e.g. two subscribes and one unsubscribe), then you need a separate 'cancel' set too, tracking the ids you removed from consideration:

```
changes = ({}, {})  # unsub, sub
changemap = {'unsubscribe': 0, 'subscribe': 1}
cancelled = set()
for action in action_list:
    if action.id_ in cancelled:
        # this action.id_ has been observed to both subscribe and unsubscribe
        # and has been cancelled altogether.
        continue

    change = changemap[action.change]  # unsubscribe / subscribe -> 0 or 1)
    if action.id_ in changes[1 - change]:
        # action is listed twice for both subscribe and unsubscribe
        # cancel opposite and ignore all further references to this action id
        del changes[1 - change][action.id_]
        cancelled.add(action.id_)
        continue

    changes[change][action.id_] = action
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be using a single hash map, counting +1 for subscriptions and -1 for unsubscriptions, and then subscribing/unsubscribing accordingly. This can be done very easily using a Python `dict`, `defaultdict`, or `Counter`. Each of those have lookup of O(1), for a total complexity of O(n) for n actions. You say that order does not matter, but with Python 3.6 and later, the dictionary will in fact retain the items in the same order they were first inserted into.

I don't know how exactly your actions are represented, so I'll just use strings like `"+1"` for "subscribe user 1". It should be easy to adapt this to your action model.

```
actions = ["+1", "-1", "+2", "+1", "+3", "+4", "-2", "-5"]

# get final (un)subscriptions
from collections import defaultdict
remaining = defaultdict(int)
for what, who in actions:
    remaining[who] += +1 if what == "+" else -1
print(remaining) # {'1': 1, '2': 0, '3': 1, '4': 1, '5': -1})
```

If there can not be any "invalid" actions (e.g. unsubscribing an already unsubscribed user), then the dict can never hold other values than +1 (subscribe), -1 (unsubscribe), or 0 (cancelled). If there *can* be invalid (un)subscriptions, it would be easy to check the current value and discard the action accordingly, e.g. by just capping the new value to `max(-1, min(value, +1))`.

Then, just iterate the values in the dictionary and print those that are left with a `+1` or `-1`:

```
# print remaining (un)subscriptions
for k, v in remaining.items():
    if v == +1:
        print("subscribe", k)
    elif v == -1:
        print("unsubscribe", k)
```

Output:

```
subscribe 1
subscribe 3
subscribe 4
unsubscribe 5
```